# Azure MS-SQL and uniqueidentifier from PHP

Tags: php, sql, azure-sql-database, uniqueidentifier

This Sql command :

```
INSERT INTO BRANCH (COMPANY,BRANCH,CODE,NAME) 
   VALUES('CC23E791-088D-4BC4-AC62-2BC9522584D5', 
          '6335E463-9A27-4FEC-8C79-239A574D254B', 
          '1000',
          'TheName')
```

always fails with error :

```
[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.
```

This commands works perfect :

```
select cast('6335E463-9A27-4FEC-8C79-239A574D254B' as unique identifier)
select cast('CC23E791-088D-4BC4-AC62-2BC9522584D5' as uniqueidentifier)
```

What is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly cast a string as a UUID, you have to supply an explicit cast to make it work. It's the equivilent of a narrowing cast in most programming languages.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but PHP's type casting is much more relaxed than SQL's is, since PHP is dynamically typed and SQL is statically typed.